# How to replace some text parts at runtime in a GTK user interface?

Tags: templates, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I’m newish to GTK programming and am working on a simple UI (python). I have a `Gtk.Assistant()` with `Gtk.Label()`s as pages. I use the labels to show some text.

Is there some text-template mechanism in GTK to replace parts of text without assigning the entire label text again? I’ve seen the pango markup, but that one does not give access to content parts like the browser DOM does. And there is that MVC part of GTK, with `TreeView` and `ListStore`, but its complexity is not what will make this simple task shorter: replace a placeholder with a number (for example).

So, is there some simple MVC aspect in GTK I’m not aware of?

Comment: It doesn't need to be built into GTK; you can implement something like that yourself. For example, if you have labels displaying the titles and authors of books, you could make a template: `template_string = "{book} was written by {author}"`. Then, you could set the text of the label to whatever book you want: `label.set_text(template_string.replace("{book}", book_name) + template_string.replace("{author}", author_name))`.

Comment: Yeah, (re)setting the text. I was just wondering if I missed something.